# How to wait without sleep?

Tags: c#, multithreading, progress-bar

I have a login form. Whenever user logs in, I want to wait some seconds to load my progress bar. Then I have to open a new form. If I use `Threed.Sleep(int)`, my progress bar is not loading.

```
while (rdr.Read())
{
    string uname = rdr["Username"].ToString().ToLower();
    string pass = rdr["Pass"].ToString();
    if (txtUname.Text.ToLower() == uname && txtPword.Text == pass)
    {
       this.logintimer.Start();
       Thread.Sleep(5000);
       InventoryForm obj = new InventoryForm();
       obj.Show();
       flag = 1;
       break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Simply don't make the user wait when they don't have any valid reason to wait, just have the progress bar track whatever it is actually supposed to track

Comment: In case there is indeed a reason to wait you can just use a timer (for example) and open the form in it's event, or use a background-task or use async, ... - just make sure to dispatch back to the UI thread

Comment: If you can mark your method async you can use `await Task.Delay(5000)`